Thought Experiment: What would happen to the UK economy if many people suddenly moved their savings into managed investment portfolios?
Different people obviously have different risk appetite and ability to sequester money away in investments, however I believe there is a large amount of money that people are keeping in savings accounts that could be earning more over long term in a managed investment portfolio.
If this population of people who perhaps could invest but aren't aware or haven't looked into it were to suddenly decide to place what they could afford into managed portfolios, what would be the effect on the economy in the UK?
How would the stock market react to the sudden buyin, would business's development be boosted by the investment?
Or is there an optimal spread of investment and bank savings accounts for an ideally healthy economy? Would the hypothetical suddenness (let's say it's a trend, 'investment goes mainstream', or triggered by a government initiative) cause undesirable volatility?
Disclaimer: I know very little about economics so apologies if this is a silly question. Thanks.
